# Updating DisplayFor Date with AJAX Result

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datetime, asp.net-mvc-5

In a view, there's a DisplayFor tied to a DateTime field in the Model.  To update the field, an AJAX call returns a Date.  I can convert the AJAX date into a MM/DD/YYYY value, but setting the DisplayFor with a .val doesn't update the view.  Chrome Developer Tools shows no error, and in fact shows the correct converted DateTime, but the DisplayFor doesn't update.  I haven't tried changing the .attr instead of the .val because it seems like .val would be the correct option.  Can anyone see why the view isn't updating?  Thanks in advance!

Model declaration:

```
DateTime? SaleDate { get; set; }
```

DisplayFor in View:

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.SaleDate, "Sale Date")
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.SaleDate, "{0:d}", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Update script inside successful AJAX call:

```
success: function (data) {
    var $sDate = $("#SaleDate");
    var pattern = /Date\(([^)]+)\)/;
    var results = pattern.exec(data[0].SaleDate);
    var dt = new Date(parseFloat(results[1]));
    $sDate.val(dt); //dt is correct Date, but DisplayFor isn't updating!
}
```

**EDIT**

The page source indicates that the id is correct, but there's no input.  I assume this is because of a DisplayFor vs. a TextBoxFor, but could the apparent absence of an id be the problem?

```
<label for="SaleDate">Sale Date</label>
6/1/2016 12:00:00 AM//no input section, just the DateTime value
```

Or, if SaleDate is null:

```
<label for="SaleDate">Sale Date</label>
//no value or input section
```

Comment: Is this ruby on rails?

Comment: No, it's C# on the Model and Controller side with Bootstrap on the View side.

Comment: Check your generated HTML code in browser to make sure your `DisplayFor` input has id `SaleDate`

Comment: @AlexKudryashev - there's no input section, per se, but the label for indicates that there is no input section or id. Thanks for the response, and I'll edit the question to include this information.

Comment: Your JS `$("#SaleDate")` expects an element with `id="SaleDate"`. and `$sDate.val(dt)` expects that this element is of input type (`input`, `select`, `textarea`). JS has now idea about Razor markup. `<label for="..."...` may point to anything existing or non-existing.

Comment: ...JS has **no** idea... ;)

Comment: @AlexKudryashev - I got it!  After I changed the DisplayFor to a read only TextBoxFor, it worked perfectly.  If you wouldn't mind writing your comment as an answer and perhaps suggesting a way to add an id, I'd be happy to mark it correct.

Comment: The `DisplayFor` will choose the html for you based on type. In this case it chose to output a bare string. You can either provide a template for `DateTime` or use a more explicit helper e.g. `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SaleDate, "{0:d}", new { @class = "form-control", id = "SaleDate" })`

Comment: @Jasen - thank you for the response.  I tried adding a new id = "SaleDate" to the DisplayFor, and it still output a bare string.  I'd like to know why, but for now, changing the DisplayFor to a TextBoxFor fixed the issue without any other changes.

Comment: Because the the string does not have an element container with an `id` attribute.

Comment: @Jasen - makes sense, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Razor code in the View produces some HTML code. Javascript works on client side and has no idea about Razor's `@Html.DisplayFor`, only about its output. I'm not strong in Razor so my offer can contain errors.
1. `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SaleDate, "{0:d}", new { @class = "form-control", id = "SaleDate" })`.
JS remains the same. Con: This is editable textbox (input)
2. `<span id="SaleDate" class="form-control">@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.SaleDate, "{0:d}")</span>`
JS last line should be `$sDate.html(dt);`

I hope it helps.